# How to create azure vmss machine as azuredevops agent

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

I was trying to setup Azure virtual machine scaleset as build agetent for on AzureDevops server. Just to confirm whether the AzureDevops server will support VMSS? What permission is required to create the vmss based build agent and is there any automation for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure DevOps Server doesn't support Azure VM ScaleSets natively for pipelines agents. That is a Azure DevOps Service feature.